# Is there an existing Data Structure like this? ( A modified Trie )

Tags: string, data-structures, graph, trie

I have been working on trie data structure recently and an alternative immediately struck to me.

For example :

[This is a trie with 2 words : football and goofball.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkpWs.png)

[This is the alternate data structure with the same words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UEtT.png)

(Each '.' is a letter in the a-z range in order)

Considering a larger dataset of valid English words, isn't the second data structure a better way to store words (link between letters) since on searching, it will give the same results but occupy far less space.

This is my thought process. I may be very well wrong or this data structure might already exist. I am here to be enlightened.

Its a theoretical approach and I am currently trying to implement it using python and test on large datasets to see if this is fruitful. But I though it would be a good idea to ask fellow members if they have had the same idea, or am I wrong or am I reinventing a wheel due to lack of exposure or lack of knowledge of nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

The second data structure is called a finite state automaton which is equivalent to the regular expression `(gt)+oo(tf)+ball`.

In Computer Science FSAs are graphs that basically define what sequence of characters are "accepted" by a "language". They have limited power but are equivalent to regular expressions.

In this case we've defined the language as `(gt)+oo(tf)+ball`.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. So if I understand your answer currently, you are saying that the second data structure is a FSA. But the data structure I made is not limited to these 2 words. In fact my curiosity is rooting from its benefit while using for vast dataset of words.
- If we consider the English dictionary and want to store them to access later, is this new data structure valid? 
- If yes, is this more efficient and comparable to prefix trees (trie)?

Comment: I don't know if it's more efficient or not.
But also the FSA can of course include the entire universe of possible words that you want. Though it may also accept words you don't want.

How does your data structure deal with unwanted letter combinations when you add too many options?

Comment: In my opinion, it doesn't need to deal with unwanted letter combinations. we keep on adding words ( link between letters ) to the structure and retrieve it later. We can either put a check before searching that the word is valid or like a trie where we use a end_of_word flag, we can use a flag or pointer. 
But this is a work in progress..more like an idea in progress. It does have its drawbacks and the aim is to identify them and work on it. But I wanted to know if its worth the effort and time or if it has been already done.